# How to get link to single post on group wall?

Tags: facebook, post, hyperlink, facebook-group

How can I get a link to single post on group wall?

I've found a link to "normal" post from user wall:

```
http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=USER_ID&id=POST_ID/
```

but it does not work for group posts.

Do you have any idea?

---

**EDIT:** 
I've found this way to show post, but it only puts selected post on the top of wall:

```
https://www.facebook.com/groups/GROUP_ID/POST_ID/
```

It's not exactly what I'm looking for. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think that's the only way to get a permalink for a group post, I've never seen a page which shows a single post only

Comment: This is probably better suited to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 36):

Hover over the time stamp of the post you want to get link for
You will find that it is a link to the post
You will find this time stamp under the post itself beside (like - comment - follow)

Comment: i think he needs programmatically

Comment: Intuitive user interface FTW ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

my group link is: https://www.facebook.com/groups/1490022297948646/

then I inspect the post (right click and inspect) and look for its ID

then I copy and add the ID to the last part of the link.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/1490022297948646/1549192568698285

It will show it on top of the group also.

Cool. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the post, where there's the name and on the right, date-time of the post mentioned, sometimes maybe time elapse instead of a date and time, clicking on that time stamp, gives you the specific URL to a post.

Answer (score 0):

I got the link to group post from activity log after liking this post, it looks like:
https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=***STORYFBID***&id=***GROUPID***

Answer (score 0):

if the single post has one and only one picture in it, the right click over it allows to copy a link address which points to this post